Comedic silent short film identification
I need help identifying a silent short film. It was probably around ten minutes and most of those ten minutes were dedicated to the credits. The "plot" of the film featured a woman walking around town with a 1910s style low cut dress and all the men being unable to continue their normal activities due to the distraction. The credits started rolling about three minutes in, and it started with a headline "FEATURING A CAST OF THOUSANDS!" and had absolutely ridiculous titles that just kept going on and on. It also had a terrible, grainy quality- the film was clearly very old and nobody had bothered to restore it or perhaps were not able to. I got the impression it was made before 1920.
I remember this being on a VHS anthology presented to my eighth grade class around 2003-4. I'm not convinced this was actually a commercially produced tape (I believe my middle school teacher mentioned he 'had to write a letter to get it'), but just in case, these are the other films that were on it:

Some kind of hilariously sexist girl vs. boy exercise comparison presented by a president (it was either JFK or Nixon, not positive).
A WWII propaganda film produced by the U.K. where they spliced clips of Nazi soldiers goosestepping to the beat of a campy foxtrot
The Bambi Meets Godzilla cartoon
De Duva, the Ingmar Bergman parody short film  that we probably should not have been watching as middle schoolers

If anybody could identify the anthology it came out of, that would also be quite excellent, but I'll accept just the identification of the silent film as it's proven very difficult to google for.

Seems it's Jules Schwerin's The [Many] Loves of Franistan from 1948, which is a minimalist satire of Hollywood epics which 'credit everyone, down to the copyboy' according to this and is mainly comprised of clips from silent films. I say "seems" because it's pretty rare and not even on IMDb, but I did find that the anthology you were looking for is called Experimental Avant Garde Series Vol. 19. It contains 5 films: the four you mentioned at the bottom (JFK Workout, Lambeth Walk Nazi style, Bambi Meets Godzilla and De Duva), and this one. This collection is available on Amazon here.

My God, this is fantastic (and the propaganda film is even on youtube!) I'd upvote you twice if I could. Now the challenge is to find somewhere to actually watch it...
